# Django ORM calculate all Members of Group

Tags: django, django-orm

I am trying to annotate all my groups by the number of Users, that apply to a certain condition. In this case I want to get a number of users, that have related Offer model to the Task in the Group.

Users can create Offers to the Task. One Task can be related to one Group.

So as the result of annotating Groups I want something like this

```
| id |  name  | runners_num |
| -- | ------ | ----------- |
| 1  | name1  |      3      |
| 2  | name2  |      5      |
```

With a query below I can get this count as a dictionary

```py
runners = User.objects.filter(
        offer__tack__group_id=1
).distinct(

).values(
    'id'
).aggregate(
    count=Count('id')
)

output: {'count': 5}
```

But I can't figure out how to do this with OuterRef clause

```py
runners = User.objects.filter(
        offer__task__group_id=OuterRef('id')
).distinct().values('id')
groups = Group.objects.annotate(
    runners_num=Count(Subquery(runners))
)
```

It ended up with this wrong query

```sql
SELECT 
  "groups"."id", 
  "groups"."name", 
  COUNT(
    (
      SELECT 
        DISTINCT U0."id" 
      FROM 
        "users" U0 
        INNER JOIN "offers" U1 ON (U0."id" = U1."runner_id") 
        INNER JOIN "tasks" U2 ON (U1."task_id" = U2."id") 
      WHERE 
        U2."group_id" = ("groups"."id")
    )
  ) AS "runners_num" 
FROM 
  "groups" 
GROUP BY 
  "groups"."id" 
LIMIT 
  21
```

My models

```py
class Task(models.Model):
    tasker = models.ForeignKey(
        "user.User", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="tasker"
    runner = models.ForeignKey(
        "user.User", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="runner",
    )
    group = models.ForeignKey(
        "group.Group",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
class Offer(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey("task.Task", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    runner = models.ForeignKey("user.User", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
class Group(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
class GroupMembers(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey("group.Group", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    member = models.ForeignKey("user.User", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

### EDIT

I have conditions where my Users get filtered. In my case I want count only Users that have more than 3 Offers that apply to conditions. So probably I can't get rid of Subquery statement and OuterRef field.

```py
runners = User.objects.filter(
    offer__task__group_id=OuterRef('id')
).distinct(
).annotate(
    offer_num=Count(
        'offer',
        filter=
        Q(
            offer__task__completion_time__isnull=False,
            offer__task__completion_time__gte=timezone.now() - timedelta(hours=24),
        ) |
        Q(
            offer__task__status__in=(
                TaskStatus.ACTIVE,
                TaskStatus.ACCEPTED,
                TaskStatus.IN_PROGRESS,
                TaskStatus.WAITING_REVIEW
            ),
            offer__task__is_active=True,
        ),
        offer__runner_id=F('id'),
    )
).filter(
    offer_num__gte=3
).values('id')
```

It is working fine if I replace OuterRef('id') with just a int Group number. But I don't know the proper solution how to count on this QuerySet. Something like

```
runners_num = Count(Subquery(runners))
```

And after that I get

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

Comment: Does `Group.objects.all().annotate(num=Count('groupmembers'))` work?- uses reverse relationships & I assume we can count on GroupMember's being unique/dependable enough. it works with the build-in `group -> user` connection with: `Group.objects.all().annotate(num=Count('user'))`

Comment: @Nealium now exactly what I want, because Users can make an Offers ta a Task and then leave the Group (GroupMembers raw will be deleted) and they will not be counting as runners, but I want to. Also I updated my conditions on whether to count User as runner or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my final solution is to carry out User's subquery and only then aggregate by Count function.

```py
users_runners = User.objects.filter(
    offer__task__group_id=OuterRef(OuterRef('id'))
).annotate(
    offer_num=Count(
        'offer',
        filter=
        Q(
            offer__task__completion_time__isnull=False,
            offer__task__completion_time__gte=timezone.now() - timedelta(hours=24),
        ) |
        Q(
            offer__task__status__in=(
                TaskStatus.ACTIVE,
                TaskStatus.ACCEPTED,
                TaskStatus.IN_PROGRESS,
                TaskStatus.WAITING_REVIEW
            ),
            offer__task__is_active=True,
        )
    )
).filter(
    offer_num__gte=3
).values(
    'id'
).distinct(

)
```

```py
runners = User.objects.filter(
    id__in=users_runners,
).annotate(
    count=Func(
        F('id'),
        function='Count'
    )
).values(
    'count'
)
```

```py
groups = Group.objects.annotate(
    runners_num=runners
).order_by(
    'id'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Annotate the number of users who have at least one offer for each group's task, correct?
I believe this should do:

```py
Group.objects.annotate(
    runners_count=Count(
        'task__offer__user', distinct=True
    )
).values('id', 'runners_count')
```

Count() has some neat kwargs you can leverage like that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Count

Comment: Seems like a very clean solution that actually works.
However I want to filter Users on conditions that I added in my Question.
And how I am understanding - I can't just put this runners Subquery into the filter argument of Count aggregation function.